# Unit testing .net classes: Exception and File.WriteAllText

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm quite new to .NET and i have some problems trying to unit test some classes.
I have a really simple .net class coded up like this:

```
using System;

namespace One.Namespace.One
{
     public class ExceptionOne : Exception
    {
    }
}
```

I can I unit test it? I tried with something like this but it isn't working

```
[TestMethod()]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ExceptionOne))]
public void ExceptionOneConstructorTest()
{
 ExceptionOne target = new ExceptionOne();
}
```

My other class is like this one

```
using System.IO;

namespace One.Write.One
{
    public class Writefile
    {
        public void Save(int result)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\db.txt",result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It would be correct to check if the file has the correct result wrote inside itself?

Comment: I can't get how your `ExceptionOne` related to writing to file. Anyway - `ExpectedException` attribute checks whether test method throws exception (that's differs from instance creation)

Comment: thanks for the answer. They are two different classes I don't know how to unit test

Comment: As it current state it does not need a unit test. The hardly has any behaviour to test. What you need is an integrstion

Comment: It looks to me this is not a unit testing concern, you need to throw an exception if the file read fail. That code is missing from your question? Then we can look at the testing concerns.

Comment: They are two different classes I want to test. I want to check if an exception is thrown if I invoke the ExceptionOne constructor and I want to test if a correct result given as input is wrote in a file. Two different tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[TestMethod()]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ExceptionOne))]
public void ExceptionOneConstructorTest()
{
 throw new ExceptionOne();
}
```

Your current code is not throwing and exception. It's just instantiating an instance of your exception class. If you want to test that you can throw your exception, try the above.

Fr your second case:
You can test that the file writing succeeded by reading back the content of the file and comparing it to the original content.